# Calling properties from class in different file with visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am working on an Assignment in MSVisual Studio using C# and downloaded a .dll that has a defined class for a drawing panel to plot points.  The defined class within this .dll has public members which I need to use for the Traveling Salesman algorithm and I have no clue how to use it.  I have tried calling the property with the class name which I am assuming is the classname.property().

```
    private Point[] _townArray;
    _townArray = Ksu.Cis300.Drawing.DrawingPanel.Points[];
```

This is the code I used in my UserInterface.cs with no luck and below are the only instruction I have on how to use these properties.

DrawingPanel

This is the class defined in the dll you downloaded above. You will need to use the following pulic members:

Points: This property gets a Point[ ] containing all the points that have been plotted on this control.

DrawLine: This method takes two Points as its parameters and draws a line on the control between them. It does not return anything.

Clear: This method takes an empty parameter list and removes all points and lines from the control. It returns nothing.

ClearLines: This method takes an empty parameter list and removes all lines from the control, leaving the points unchanged. It returns nothing.

Comment: You should instantiate an object from the class, to call it's non-static members. See [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/new).

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add the library to the project by right clicking on references and the Add Reference.  You are going to need to add the library with a using statement in the code.  You will need to instantiate the class to access the properties and methods.  See below.

```
using TravelSalesClass;
using System.Drawing;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SalesAlgorithm salesAlgorithm = new SalesAlgorithm();
        Point[] points = salesAlgorithm.Points;

        //draw a line between 2 points
        salesAlgorithm.DrawLine(points[0], points[1]);

        //clear all points and lines
        salesAlgorithm.Clear();

        //clear lines
        salesAlgorithm.ClearLines();           

    }
}
```

}

Example library

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace TravelSalesClass{
public class SalesAlgorithm
{
    public SalesAlgorithm() { }
    public Point[] Points { get; set; }
    public void DrawLine(Point point1, Point point2) { }
    public void Clear() { }
    public void ClearLines() { }

}
```

}